# Как правильно проверять, можно ли двигаться спрайту в платформере на pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Нужно, чтобы спрайт персонажа мог прыгать и двигаться вправо-влево, если ему не мешает препятствие. Я хотел написать что-то типа

```py
if is_move_right and spritecollideany(self, # группа с препятствиями):
    is_move_right = False
```

и так с остальными направлениямию
Но тогда возникает проблема: когда персонаж стоит на препятствии сверху, он не может двигаться ни вправо, ни влево, так как коллизия уже есть. Подскажите, как это все правильно прописать, хотя бы идею дайте. Спасибо.

Comment: Направление движения: Создать карту препятствий, и двигаться только по карте. Зачем Вам группа?

Comment: https://github.com/Mekire/pygame-samples/blob/master/four_direction_movement/four_dir_obstacles.py  - не поможет?